# Где брать svg, png иконки и как их использовать для разных разрешений экрана?

Tags: html, css, svg, img

Не могу найти иконку в svg, решаю добавлять ее через обычное png. Хочу сделать так, чтоб вне зависимости от разрешения экрана все смотрелось хорошо.

Вопрос: где именно искать версии картинок в 2x, 3x? Их дизайнер сам добавляет в макет? Или это ищешь самостоятельно?

Comment: Самому ручками добавлять в коллекцию. Далее описывать css на все нужные разрешения

Comment: К вопросу где искать версии картинок это пожалуй вопрос к штатному дизайнеру а не верстальщику

Comment: @Aziz Umarov  Как добавлять в css я знаю. Что вы подразумеваете под "коллекцией"? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: svg может хранить в себе много данных

Comment: иконки можно самому нарисовать ..не сложно вроде

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> где именно искать версии картинок в 2x, 3x? Их дизайнер сам добавляет
> в макет? Или это ищешь самостоятельно?

### PNG иконки

Если это иконки png, то достаточно много пакетов иконок в сети, где включены несколько папок с размерами `32. 64, 128, 256px`

Если нужно, свою, родную иконку в нескольких вариантах размеров, то можно в `Photoshop` или в другом растровом редакторе сделать это. Буквально в несколько кликов, - нужно только выставить в меню изменения размеров требуемые цифры.

### SVG иконки

*Сначала ссылки на ресурсы, где достаточно много иконок и изображений SVG*

1. http://thenewcode.com/assets/svg/
2. http://svg-whiz.com/svg/
3. https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/
4. https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f698.svg

В п.4 нет открытого каталога со списком иконок, но их можно посмотреть и скачать, если в браузерной строке поиска подставлять цифры с `300` до `699`

`https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f301.svg`

[image]

***Пример, как использовать одну и ту же иконку с разными выводимыми размерами***

Допустим вы скачали иконку андроида

Код иконки:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35%" height="35%" viewBox="0 0 96 105">
  <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
  <g fill="#FFF">
    <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
    <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Необходимо её немного доработать:

1.Обернуть код в тег `<symbol id="icon">`

2. И далее, ей можно многократно использовать, вызывая командой `<use>`

   ```html
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 105" >
         <symbol id="icon" viewBox="0 0 96 105"> 
        <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
           <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
           <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
         </g>
         <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
         <g fill="#FFF">
           <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
           <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
         </g>
         </symbol> 
           
        <use xlink:href="#icon" x="0" width="30%" height="30%"  /> 
           <use xlink:href="#icon" x="25" width="20%" height="20%" />
             <use xlink:href="#icon" x="42 " width="10%" height="10%" /> 
               <use xlink:href="#icon" x="52" width="5%" height="5%" />
       </svg>
   ```